# Rerender when reassign scope variable

Tags: angularjs

When my controller intitializes it loads items and they are populated with `ng-repeat` in simple list.

I have refresh method that will requery items from service:

```
$scope.items = Service.queryREST()
                      .then(function (result) {               
                          return result.data;
                       });
```

The problem is that when list is already rendered it **dissapears** and rerenders only after `queryREST` will get result.

How can I get rid of this rerender problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the ng-repeat iterate over the promise returned by `queryREST()`. BTW, that won't work anymore in angular 1.2. Make it iterate over the result of the promise:

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.refreshItems = function() {
    Service.queryREST()
           .then(function(result) {               
               $scope.items = result.data;
           });
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    ...
</div>
```